# Code to fetch Data from 2 tables & enter in 3rd Table in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Table1 - Payout Requests
`

```
|--------|-----------|-----------|
|  id    |  Receiver |  Balance  |
|--------|-----------|-----------|
|  1     |  user1    |  2000     |
|--------|-----------|-----------|
|  2     |  user2    |  1500     |
|--------|-----------|-----------|`
```

---

Table2 - Donars

```
`
|--------|-----------|-----------|
|  id    |  Donar    |  Amount   |
|--------|-----------|-----------|
|  1     |  love     |  1500     |
|--------|-----------|-----------|
|  2     |  don1     |  1000     |
|--------|-----------|-----------|`
```

---

Now my question; What piese of code will make Adjustments of both the tables so that data from these two tables goes in 3rd table in the following way

---

Table3 - Links
`

```
|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
|  id    |  Donar    |  Receiver |  Amount  |
|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
|  1     |  love     |  user1    |  1500    | 
|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
|  2     |  don1     |  user1    |  500     |
|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
|  3     |  don1     |  user2    |  500     |
|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|`
```

---

---

AND now Table 1 & Table 2 will be Follows -

Table1 - Payout Requests
`

```
|--------|-----------|-----------|
|  id    |  Receiver |  Balance  |
|--------|-----------|-----------|
|  2     |  user2    |  1000     |
|--------|-----------|-----------|`
```

---

Table2 - Donars
`

```
|--------|-----------|-----------|
|  id    |  Donar    |  Amount   |
|--------|-----------|-----------|
|           Nothing              |
|--------|-----------|-----------|`
```

Comment: do you also want to delete rows from your db?

Comment: @KP. No all rows will remain in all tables as it is, all i want to know is HOW TO MAKE AMOUNT's ADJUSTMENT Here. ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first step you should have a foreign key on Donars table which save id of Payout Requests. for example pr_id

You can use INNER JOIN like this:

```
SELECT `t2`.`id`, `t2`.`Donar`, `t1`.`Receiver `, `t1`.Balance - `t2`.`Amount` AS `Adjustment` FROM `table1` AS `t1` INNER JOIN `table2` AS `t2` ON `t2`.`pr_id` = `t1`.id
```

Comment: How can i make amount adjustments in this query ??

Comment: can you please more explain "amount adjustments"

Comment: For Example, if 'user1' from table1 needed 2000 amount but 'love' in table2 has only 1500, so he has to take remaining 500 from 'don1' of same table (i.e, table2) & remaining amount of 'don1' will automatically goes to 'user2'

Comment: check `t1`.Balance - `t2`.`Amount` AS `Adjustment` in my edited post

Comment: Can you please write me whole script in one go, as i am new to php ??

Comment: as i mentioned in the post first create pr_id and after that add id to that and run this query with PHP and get data do you need question on converting query to php?

Comment: And what is "pr_id" here exactly???

Comment: it is id of Payout Requests which save on Donars table as foreign key

Comment: 1. can i run this query in while loop, if say i has 1000s entry in both tables with different "balance & amount" figures of each entry in both tables?
2. Will it show any -ve balance if according to your query balance > amount?

Comment: can you please more explain

Comment: Say i want to run these 3 table's query or function or what-ever-it-is; from a single button in my admin panel. Like an "Auto Payment Button" in which system matches "Payout Requests" against "Donations Balance" & pay 1st payout request from 1st donar's balance. If any Unpaid amount remains of 1st payout request will Automatic get adjust against 2nd donar's balance OR vice-versa, where 1st payout request is less than 1st Donar's Balance, in this case Donar's Remaining Balance will automatically get paid to 2nd payout request & so on & so on .......

Comment: you can do all process with this query and those are just calculations on that

Comment: Will it not give any -ve balance if balance is less than amount, According to your query ???

Comment: int he query if Adjustment is more than 0 it has balance other wise user does not have balance to pay for that  Donars.

Comment: ok, thanks Majid Abbasi, can i have your email, if in any case i have any further issue??